# Proper naming convention for html elements

Tags: html

i usually name my html elements with prefix like btn for buttons, txt for textbox, chk for checkbox, rad for radio buttons, etc.

however, one of my colleague pointed out that this is not a proper way to do it. he said that you should not use this prefix, instead just name it like **saverecord** for submit button instead of **btnsaverecord**.

my point of doing this is that i can easily knew what element was defined on a certain situation, for example:

for PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST["btnsaverecord"]))
```

for COLDFUSION:

```
<cfif structkeyexists(form, "btnsaverecord")>
```

is there any common-majority practice on how to really name these elements?

Comment: The question is: does it matter *what* provided the value, so long as you actually get that value?

Comment: it does, because we are arguing as we are trying to create some kind of standard coding practice for the organization. im just wondering if there are some kind of majority practice for this.